# PitchiPoy Rigify missing finger controls

Tags: rigify

I have a problem, I am using the rigify tool in blender. Not the normal rigify but the one form PichtiPoy with the faceial controls. I love it but with the normal rigify tool you get the nice finger controls, where you just have to scale something down and the fingers wil close. I find thant very useful but I can't find it anywhere on the PitchiPoy version of the add-on.

Can sombody tell me what the problem is? What I'm doing wrong or how I could make it work?
I would love to hear it!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to switch.

First you need to select the **Pitchiboy metarig** and go into **Pose mode**. Select the root of the finger (3rd from the tip) and go to the **Bone properties** view. Under the **Rigify Type** view it shows that the bone is set to create a *"pitchiboy.simple_tentacle"*.

[image: Rig type set to pitchiboy.simple_tentacle]

Click the **Rig type** field and select *"finger"*. You need to do this to each finger you want to change.

[image: Rig type set to finger]

Now when you **generate the rig**, you'll have the default finger controls. The Rigify system is pretty flexible, allowing you to mish and mash rig controls any way you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have played with this rig as well and it is awesome! What I tend to do is create the PitchiPoy meta rig, delete all but the face bones (everything from "head" down inclusive). Than I create the regular rig and join the face rig to it (select the face rig, than the other meta rig, and hit ctrl+j to join). Then I click "generate" which gives me the default old style rig (finger scale widgets included) with PitchiPoy's face rig which is amazing.

The problem is that PitchiPoy's rig uses different finger controls. If you "rotate" the root of the finger, the entire finger curls. Its a bit different set up so it just depends on your preference. I think I could get used to it, but I am still using my method.

The above method of changing the rig type to finger also works if you want to use all of PitchiPoy's rig.