# Error rigging with Pitchipoy skeleton

Tags: rigging, rigify

As a rigging noob, I am drawn to use the Pitchipoy skeleton from the Rigify addon, but I am struggling to make sense of the following error code that keeps the metarig from generating anything at all.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\rigify\ui.py", line 286, in execute
generate.generate_rig(context, context.object)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 293, in generate_rig
raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\rigify\generate.py", line 281, in generate_rig
scripts = rig.generate()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\rigify\rigs\pitchipoy\limbs\super_limb.py", line 499, in generate
bones['fk']     = self.create_fk(  bones['parent']        )
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\rigify\rigs\pitchipoy\limbs\super_limb.py", line 399, in create_fk
eb[ ctrls[2] ].parent      = eb[ mch      ]
IndexError: list index out of range

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

To me, the error message suggests that the problem mostly has to do with the Pitchipoy files, but to be on the safe side, these are the screenshots before and after my attempts to generate.

[image: Please excuse the nudity]

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/43095

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bone won't move in rigify](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60839/bone-wont-move-in-rigify)

Answer (score 2):

Pitchipoy is very sensitive - meaning you can't change anything except the position of the bones. You cannot change names and you certainly can't change bones. If you add a new Pitchipoy rig and enter edit mode you will see it has 159 bones. Your rig has 157 meaning you delete 2 bones and hence broke the rig.

Updated: Not completely true that you can't add bones - that is possible in Edit mode > Rigify Buttons > Add Samples. Helpful information is also in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27205/pitchipoy-rigify-missing-finger-controls) on changing the finger controls.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suppose this is true for the vanilla rigify skeleton as well?

Comment: Yep. They both run scripts in the background that check the position of the bones. The bone names, relationships and hierarchies are interdependent and can't be changed. However, you can make additions and some changes after the rig has been generated.