# How do I adjust limbs.simple_tentacle to finger?

Tags: rigify

My question derives from the given link here..

[PitchiPoy Rigify missing finger controls](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27205/pitchipoy-rigify-missing-finger-controls)

I am trying to change from "simple tentacle" to "finger" have no "rigify type" option available, and just writing finger into the "rigify_type" down on the right doesnt change it..

[image]

thats what I would like to have.. -->

[image]

How do I do this?
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change limbs.simple_tentacle to limbs.simple_fingers

Comment: Adding a screenshot or some details on where and how to achieve that would make it easier to understand.

Comment: You set it on the metarig
In pose mode
select the base of the three finger bones
Under the Bone properties Tab, Rigify Type. The drop down next to Rig Type has a whole bunch of rig type options. The one you are looking for here is the limbs.super_Finger.

When you generate the rig you'll see the controls you want. on the bones you set to that rig Type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an illustration
[image]
You set the rig type on the metarig **before** generating the control rig.

- Select the Metarig and set it to pose mode.
- select the base of the three finger bones.
- open the Bone properties Tab
- Expand the Rigify Type section
- In the drop down next to Rig Type you'll see a bunch of rig type options. The one you are looking for here is the **limbs.super_Finger.**
- You can then select the bases of all the other fingers and Right click on the Rigify Type and select Copy to selected so you don't have to manually set them all one by one.
- Once that's done, you generate the rig and you'll see the controls you want on the bones you set to that rig Type.